# How to resolve ambiguous associated type with NetRc

Tags: rust

I'm trying to make curl-rust optionally [make use of a ~/.netrc file](https://docs.rs/curl/latest/curl/easy/enum.NetRc.html), but I cannot make it compile:

```
use curl::easy::Easy;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {

    let urlstring = "https://example.com/";
    let mut easy = Easy::new();

    // Setting some curl options
    easy.url(urlstring)?;
    easy.fail_on_error(true)?;
    easy.netrc(Easy::NetRc::Optional)?;

    // Main activity goes here

    Ok(())
}
```

When building, I keep getting the following error:

```
error[E0223]: ambiguous associated type
  --> src/main.rs:11:16
   |
11 |     easy.netrc(Easy::NetRc::Optional)?;
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^ help: use fully-qualified syntax: `<Easy as Trait>::NetRc`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0223`.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case the *error seems misleading*.

From the [documentation](https://docs.rs/curl/0.4.42/curl/easy/enum.NetRc.html), `NetRc` emun lives under the `curl::easy` module, not part of the `Easy` struct.
Just **bring it to scope** as you did with `Easy` itself:

```rust
use curl::easy::{Easy, NetRc};

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {

    let urlstring = "https://example.com/";
    let mut easy = Easy::new();

    // Setting some curl options
    easy.url(urlstring)?;
    easy.fail_on_error(true)?;
    easy.netrc(NetRc::Optional)?;

    // Main activity goes here

    Ok(())
}
```

Or use the full path:

```rust
easy.netrc(curl::easy::NetRc::Optional)?;
```